# Creating Raster Colorizer with ArcPy for ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcpy, raster, arcgis-pro, colormap

I'm having trouble trying to write the Colorizer code for an NDVI Raster in ArcGIS Pro.

The raster is single band, and if I set the discrete colorizer through the Symbology window, I then can access the colorizer through ArcPy after creating a lyr.symbology object, and manipulate it from there.

However I'm at a loss as to how to create the colorizer from scratch.

What workflow will work?

I presume it it has to do with the _getcolorizer option in symbology, but that's as far as I've got.

```
    n_sim = lyr.symbology
    n_sim._getColorizer('RasterClassifyColorizer')
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
    In  [8]:
    Line 1:     n_sim._getColorizer('RasterClassifyColorizer')

    TypeError: _getColorizer() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

This returns the above error

```
    n_sim._getColorizer = 'RasterClassifyColorizer'
```

This doesn't return an error, but the workflow escapes me.

Comment: What kind of symbol do you want? Classified?

Comment: Classified Colorizer